# Applications refuse to start; "Could not load QT plugin ubuntumirclient"

Tags: qt, mir

I have been trying to build applications from the source and they compile perfectly. But when I go to run them, I get this error:
    This program failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "ubuntumirclient".
    Available platform plugins are: eglfs, kms, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, mirserve, wayland-egl, wayland, xcb.
    Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
I am running xubuntu 15.10.
Any clues as to why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a Mir library on Xubuntu.

Mir is a very new technology, and is being developed primarily on Unity7 with the Ubuntu SDK, which means that it is pivotal for Canonical Developers to ensure that Ubuntu 15.10 will not have these issues. If you switch to Ubuntu 15.10, you will have the native and recommended developer environment, and subsequently, this should take care of all these dependency issues.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of the Mir library so that I can just use xubuntu. Note: I get the same problem when I download the (fully compiled) application telegram and try to run it.

Comment: Just curious; did you try any of these dependencies: http://i.imgur.com/qQtgijG.png